# how to install ssl on load balancer in amazon elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, load-balancing, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront

Can anybody tells me How to install/configure SSL on Elastic Load balancer in Elastic Beanstalk Environment???

I have followed the methods given in in the links below to run my site with https:// but ssl does not work for me.

1). https://medium.com/@arcdigital/enabling-ssl-via-aws-certificate-manager-on-elastic-beanstalk-b953571ef4f8#.qg1rvkz3o
Error encountered when followed the above link as 
Could not connect to the endpoint URL

2). http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html

Although i have been issued an SSL certificate by the amazon certificate manager and has status issued.

Helpful links required Please,

Comment: "Could not connect to the endpoint URL" sounds like an issue with the HTTPS port configuration on your ELB, not a SSL configuration issue. Why don't you post your ELB port configuration.

Comment: Does your ELB contain a listener for 443 port?

Comment: when i am adding listener for port 443 on the load balancer it shows me error message as 

"Secure listeners require a SSL certificate": http://screencast.com/t/E6jSHBfVSH

whereas i have a signed certificate by amazon which should be selected here. but when i am selecting the certificate by selecting the change option it should not allow me to select the existing certificate.

can be shown here: http://screencast.com/t/k5974IFJBX4

Comment: i have a signed certificate which can be shown as: http://screencast.com/t/xVSa7cm5I

but when i am trying to select the certificate in the SSL Certificate ID field, it does not allow me to select my signed certificate

http://screencast.com/t/9JrgLQZu